# Sharing a file among several processes [Perl]

Tags: perl, process, ipc

I have an application that updates a CSV file (single one), the CSV is being updated randomly from several processes, and I guess if two processes try to update it (add a row...) on the same time, some data will be lost I guess, or overwritten(?).

what is the best way to avoid this?

thanks,

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather would wanna use some sort of database. If you'd really wanna continue with the CSV, I'd recommend using [flock()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) but you'd have to rewrite your processes to be able to wait for the file to be available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Perl's [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/) with the [DBD::CSV driver](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/DBD-CSV/) to access your data; that'll take care of the `flock`ing for you. (Unless you're using Windows 95 or the old Mac OS.) If you decide to switch to an RDBMS later on, you'll be well prepared.

Simple `flock`ing as suggested by @Fluff should also be fine, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a simple and manual way to take care of file locking.

```
1) As soon as a process opens the csv, it creates a lock.
  (Lock can be in the form of creating a dummy file. The process has to delete 
  the file(lock) as soon as it is done reading/updating the csv)
2) Have each process check for file lock before trying to update the csv.
 (If dummy file is present, some process is accessing the csv, 
  else it can update the csv)
```